# Site down after change in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an URL called ifbil.dk. On this page I have a few subdirectories, such as ifbil.dk/dev. I tried to redirect pages on the domain via the .htaccess. After i did this, the site went down with the server not being found.

I'm really unsure what to do, to reclaim the page. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

My original .htaccess file looks like this right now:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a problem with dns, so the problem is not caused by htaccess and cant be resolved by it